# hive log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, ambari

Hello how to fixe this issues? When I try to launch hive in my commande line(I'm using amazone aws instance and ambari is well started only 3 CRIT in YARN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code from

```
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
```

To

```
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

in `log4j.properties`

`DailyRollingFileAppender` doesn't support MaxFileSize, RollingFileAppender does.

Comment: Hello thanks for tgis quick answer. Where to get the file log4j.properties? I’m using aws instance.

Comment: Try going to path: `/etc/hive/conf`

find a file called `hive-log4j.properties`.